# SELECT query fails using PDO, works in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Database

```
start                  end
2012-07-21 15:40:00    2012-07-28 21:00:00
2012-07-23 20:00:00    2012-07-27 13:00:00
```

this is what I run through phpMyAdmin and returned me the correct rows

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `events` 
WHERE  "2012-07-25 15:40"
BETWEEN START AND END
```

But on my php code, that I posted just below I can not get any results. (all the data submitted by the form are posted 100% ). What am I missing?

```
$question= 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE ';

$hasTime = false;
if(!empty($time)) { // @note better validation here
    $hasTime = true;
    $question .= 'WHERE time=:time BETWEEN start AND end';
}
$hasCity = false;
if(!empty($city)) { // @note better validation here
    $hasCity = true;
    $question .= 'AND city=:city ';
}
$hasType = false;
if(!empty($type)) { // @note better validation here
    $hasType = true;
    $question .= 'AND type=:type';
}

$query = $db->prepare($question);

if($hasTime)
    $query->bindValue(":time", $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($hasCity)
    $query->bindValue(":city", $city, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($hasType)
    $query->bindValue(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$query->execute();
```

Comment: What is the actual resulting SQL query from this code?  It looks like it has much more in its `WHERE` clause than just what you tested in PHPMyAdmin.  Also, it may have a syntax error or two.  For example, it looks like you're doubling the `WHERE` keyword.  I imagine the database would be returning an error if that's the case.  Is it?

Comment: PDO::PARAM_INT - that should be string not int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$question= 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE ';

$hasTime = false;
if(!empty($time)) { // @note better validation here
    $hasTime = true;
    $question .= 'WHERE time=:time BETWEEN start AND end';
}
```

You will end up with `WHERE` in your query twice, which is a syntax error. Change

```
$question .= 'WHERE time=:time BETWEEN start AND end';
```

to

```
$question .= 'time=:time BETWEEN start AND end';
```

**EDIT**

Use this code instead. This avoids the other potential syntax errors you will get if the `time` is not specified.

```
// Store where clauses and values in arrays
$values = $where = array();

if (!empty($time)) { // @note better validation here
    $where[] = ':time BETWEEN `start` AND `end`';
    $values[':time'] = $time;
}

if (!empty($city)) { // @note better validation here
    $where[] = '`city` = :city';
    $values[':city'] = $city;
}

if (!empty($type)) { // @note better validation here
    $where[] = '`type` = :type';
    $values[':type'] = $type;
}

// Build query
$question = 'SELECT * FROM `events`';
if (!empty($where)) {
    $question .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);
}

$query = $db->prepare($question);

$query->execute($values);
```

Comment: True, I have added mistakenly a second WHERE. However even though that I deleted it, I still can't get any rows.

Comment: @Kaoukkos edited again. If it's still not working, please show the value you have stored in `$time`

Comment: @Kaoukkos Just spotted another mistake and fixed it in my code. `time=:time BETWEEN start AND end` should just be `:time BETWEEN start AND end` (remove the `time=`)

Comment: Great answer. thank you very much for your help. I checked it and it works perfectly. Again, thank you.

Comment: Do you find it a better solution to work with array instead of my "solution" ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos Using an array for the `WHERE` clause avoids all the complication you get when there is a possibility that there will be nothing to put in it (i.e. if all the arguments in your code are empty). It means that you don't have to worry about trimming an additional `AND` off the query (something I see here *a lot*) and all that nonsense. Using an array for the values means that you don't have to do all that messing about with `bindValue()` and you can just pass it directly to `execute()`

Comment: @Kaoukkos It also avoids littering the current scope with those extra boolean flags to indicate when a parameter is present (`$hasTime` etc)